# Trazas durante desarrollo Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero introducir mensajes de trazado durante el desarrollo de una *app* en *Android* para que me aparezcan en el panel de mensajes `Run` al lanzar el emulador, como si hiciera p.e. un `System.out.println( "xxx" );` con `JAVASE` y poder ver un poco por donde va la ejecución.

Quise emplear la clase **Trace**, pero requiere la `API level 18` y estoy usando la *16*.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las técnicas más útiles a la hora de depurar y/o realizar el seguimiento de aplicaciones sobre cualquier plataforma es la creación de logs de ejecución. Android por supuesto no se queda atrás y nos proporciona también su propio servicio y API de logging a través de la clase android.util.Log.

En Android, todos los mensajes de log llevarán asociada la siguiente información:

Fecha/Hora del mensaje.
Criticidad. Nivel de gravedad del mensaje (se detalla más adelante).
PID. Código interno del proceso que ha introducido el mensaje.
Tag. Etiqueta identificativa del mensaje (se detalla más adelante).
Mensaje. El texto completo del mensaje.
De forma similar a como ocurre con otros frameworks de logging, en Android los mensajes de log se van a clasificar por su criticidad, existiendo así varias categorias (ordenadas de mayor a menor criticidad):

Error
Warning
Info
Debug
Verbose
Para cada uno de estos tipos de mensaje existe un método estático independiente que permite añadirlo al log de la aplicación. Así, para cada una de las categorías anteriores tenemos disponibles los métodos e(), w(), i(), d() y v() respectivamente.

public class LogsAndroid extends Activity {

```
private static final String LOGTAG = "LogsAndroid";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de error");
    Log.w(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de warning");
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de información");
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de depuración");
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de verbose");
}
```

}

La información la obtuve del siguiente enlace :

http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/depuracion-en-android-logging/

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, si gracias, ya encontré la clase Log e hice algunas pruebas.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

Para esto esta destinado [el **LogCat**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html), dentro de tu Android Monitor puedes filtrar los mensajes configurados por prioridad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que son:

```
V — Verbose (más baja prioridad)
D — Debug
I — Info
W — Warning
E — Error
A — Assert
```

A estos mensajes puedes configurar una etiqueta y el mensaje o datos que deseas monitorear, por ejemplo, definimos 2 mensajes tipo Debug al iniciar y al terminar una aplicación:

```
   Log.d("MiApp", "inicia mi aplicación :" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

y

```
  Log.d("MiApp", "termino mi aplicación " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Al ejecutar normalmente tu aplicación y revisar en el LogCat puedes ver diversos mensajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si los filtramos por la etiqueta "MiApp" podemos localizar rápidamente la información que necesitamos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso los puedes filtrar por el texto definido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas información:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLogging/article.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/depuracion-en-android-logging/

http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android-fundamentos/31-unidad-1-vision-general-y-entorno-de-desarrollo/470-depurar-con-mensajes-log